# Is it possible to make fabric text have padding using dimensions?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

If I have a fabric text object can I add a number to the left and top properties and start subtracting from the dimensions to emulate padding?

ex:

```
let padding = 4;
let left = textObject.left + padding;
let top = textObject.top + padding;
let width = textObject.width - (2 * padding);
let height = textObject.height - (2 * padding);

textObject.set({left: left, top: top, width: width, height: height});
textObject.setCoords();
```

Comment: try `textObject.set({padding:4});`

Comment: Oh thanks I'll give it a try. Hopefully the version I am using has that. Is there a paddingX or paddingY too?